# LP with binary constraint coefficient matrix

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Suppose I have the following LP:

\begin{align}
\underset{x}{max.} \quad & \sum_i^n c_{i}x_{i} \\
s.t. \quad & \mathbf{A}x \leq b, \; \mathbf{A} \in \{0,1\}^{m \times n}, b \in \mathbb{R}^{m}  \\
& 0 \leq x \leq x_{max}, \; x, x_{max} \in \mathbb{R}^n
\end{align}

Is there a specific name for this problem structure, especially due to the binary constraint coefficient matrix? Surprisingly, I have not been able to find anything (caused by incompetence, I am afraid). Could you point me towards any resources discussing structure and solution of the problem?